# Should I use a double or triple broadhead for boars?

Tags: archery, bow-hunting, boars

A triple broadhead has three edges equally attached around the shaft while a double broadhead has only two blades.

Triple broadhead:
[image: Triple broadhead]

So, which one should one use to hunt boars? A double- or triple-edged arrowhead?

Note: I want to shoot a [60#@29"](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10008/whats-meant-by-poundage-or-weight-of-a-bow) (draw weight of 60 pounds at a draw length of 29 inches) recurve bow.

> Draw weight:
>
> The force required to hold the string stationary at full draw is often
>   used to express the power of a bow, and is known as its draw weight,
>   or weight.
>
> Draw length:
>
> The maximum distance the string could be displaced and thus the
>   longest arrow that could be loosed from it, a bow’s draw length, is
>   determined by the size of the archer.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bow_and_arrow
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead

Comment: Can you explain `60#@29"` for people who maybe taking this up and are just learning? The fuller your description in questions the better :)

Answer (score 6):

Three blade broadheads will leave a wider wound channel and thus a better chance for a kill as bow kills are usually blood loss.  It can be argued that two blade gets better penetration but, in my opinion, that is just a factor of putting your shot in the right place.  Failure to hit the target isn't an arrow problem.

(Edit:  Okay yes, failure to hit could be an arrow problem, but it's not a function of double vs. triple)