# Is there a minimum poundage required for bow hunting?

Tags: bow-hunting, australia

I want to go on a hunt in Australia. I'm normally quite close to the minimum poundage limit (around 52 pound). This makes me ask if there is a minimum poundage in Australia and - of course - if yes, what the minimum is?

Comment: Please explain what minimum poundage is -- something to do with the pull on bow?  But what?  And, if you could, why it matters, legally.  Just curious.

Comment: @ab2 your comment could be a question on its own! :-)

Comment: I now know what poundage is from http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9984/should-i-use-a-double-or-triple-broadhead-for-boars.  Is there a minimum poundage to avoid merely wounding an animal?

Comment: @ab2 There's is often a minimum requirement (in the EU normally 55#) for your bow. It's how much you have to pull the string to get it to 28" (from bow to hand). Compare it to a vehicle's "horse power". I'll make a Q&A entry for this topic.

Comment: @ab2 Hope this helps a little bit: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10008/whats-meant-by-poundage-or-weight-of-a-bow/10009#10009

Comment: @OddDeer Also not many people remember that `#` is called a pound sign, especially in the UK were a `£` is a pound sign, a lot of people just know it as a hash tag now a days!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the "[Australian Bowhunters Association](https://www.bowhunters.org.au/)" there is no minimum requirement.

> Q: What the minimum bow poundage required to hunt in Australia?
>
> Answer
>
> The ABA has no minimum recommendation on poundage for hunting. There
>   are State regulations that require minimum standards of poundage and
>   arrow weight. In Victoria these are specifically for deer. 50 and 45
>   pound depending on the species.
>
> The ABA recommends that you hunt at distances which will enable the
>   hunter to have, as far as practicable, quick clean kills.
>
> This obviously has to have some regard to the maximum poundage you can
>   shoot effectively.

From [ABA - Bowhunting FAQ](https://www.bowhunters.org.au/index.php/50-bowhunting/58-bowhunting-faq-s)